# Solving linear vector differential equations with repeated eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RepeatedEigenvalues.aspx

This gives an example of how to solve such systems. But I have a problem. what if the eigenspace due to an eigenvalue has dimension greater than one? Then there is more than one potential eigenvector (letter which looks like $n$). Will I have to get more solutions using that?

Comment: if your matrix is $A,$ and you have Jordan form $J$ with $P^{-1}JP=A,$ it then follows that $$ e^{At} = P^{-1}e^{Jt}P. $$ It is simple to write $e^{Jt}$ since $J= D+N$  is the sum of a diagonal and a nilpotent that commute, so $$ e^{Jt} = e^{Dt}e^{Nt} = e^{Nt}e^{Dt} $$

Answer (score 0):

What the linked page neglects to mention is that it’s possible even for a $2\times2$ matrix to have an eigenvalue with both algebraic and geometric multiplicity of $2$. (If it’s a $2\times2$ matrix, then it must be a multiple of the identity.) In that case you can find a pair of linearly independent eigenvectors with that eigenvalue and just use the basic solution as described in an earlier section: for each eigenvector $\vec\eta$, you have a term of the form $ce^{\lambda t}\vec\eta$.

Comment: so do we apply the process to each eigenvector? It would give too many independent solutions..

Comment: so do they really mean 'repeated eigenvectors'?

Comment: @Dis-integrating There’s no such thing as a “repeated eigenvector.” With two linearly-independent eigenvectors you get two independent solutions, which is exactly how many you need.

Comment: /i mean like when the eigenspace has dimension equal to 2 for a repeated eigenvalue, then you don't have to do this?

Comment: @Dis-integrating You don’t have to do this for any eigenvalue that has equal geometric and algebraic multiplicities.